# Python create a sorted list from file using append remove duplicate words

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, append

I am currently working in a python course and I am lost on this after 6 hrs +. Assignment directs student to create a program where the user enters a file name and python opens the file and builds a sorted word list with out duplicates. Directions are very clear that For loop and append must be used. " For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list."

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
for words in fh:
    if words in 1st:continue
        elif 1st.append
1st.sort()
print 1st
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: Your algorithm is off, but, more importantly, you're using thoroughly incorrect syntax. I suggest you go back and review your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the following loop is supposed to do -

```
for words in fh:
    if words in 1st:continue
        elif 1st.append
```

The above does not do anything because you have already exhausted the file `fh` before control reaches this part.

You should put an inner loop inside - `for line in fh:` - that goes over the words in `words` list one by one and appends to `lst` if its not already there.

Also, you should do `lst.append(word)`

Also, i do not think your `if..elif` block is valid syntax either.

You should be doing something like xample -

```
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
```

Comment: What is the point of putting the continue?  I think this is bad style.  Just check if `if word not in 1st:` instead.  I know the end result is a loop if we don't append either way.

Comment: True , corrected , I had just used what OP has in his other loop

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just use the `set()` by itself, but this would be a good implementation per the assignment instructions.  It's really fast compared to a `list` only version!

```
from collections import Set

def get_exclusive_list(fname):
    words = []
    with open(fname.txt, 'r') as file_d:
        data = file_d.read()
    [words.extend(li.split(' ')) for li in data.splitlines()]
    data = []
    already_seen = set()
    for thing in words:
        if thing not in already_seen:
            data.append(thing)
            already_seen.add(thing)
return data


# The better implementation
def get_exclusive_list_improved(fname):
    words = []
    with open(fname.txt, 'r') as file_d:
        data = file_d.read()
    [words.extend(li.split(' ')) for li in data.splitlines()]
    return list(set(words))
```

Comment: It's  half the lines of code to my fingers.  It is only a constant faster than it's counterpart.